# Charis SIL font produces ? instead of IPA symbols

Tags: fontspec, linguistics

I'm trying to type IPA symbols into LaTeX for the first time (instead of using tipa) and for some reason, the IPA symbols aren't being recognized like I want them to. I'm using Charis SIL, compiling in XeLaTeX (but LuaLaTeX produces the same result) and the basic code is this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Charis SIL}

\begin{document}

dʒa

\end{document}
```

...which produces 'd?a' instead of 'dʒa' in the PDF:

[image]

Any suggestions for how to fix this?

Comment: works okay for me. Show the log-file of lualatex.

Comment: May be, rephrase the title of the question...!

Answer (score 3):

I can’t reproduce your bug on TeX Live 2020.

First, make sure you have an up-to-date version of Charis SIL.  When I check `otfinfo -i $(kpsewhich CharisSIL-R.ttf)`, it tells me that I have version 5.000 of the font.

Second, check which copy of the font you are actually loading.  It’s possible you have an obsolete one somewhere.  The full path of every font you load should be in the console output and the `.log` file.

Third, it’s generally a good idea to add the command `\tracinglostchars=2` to your source file, so TeX will warn you if the current font is missing a character.  By default, it buries the message in the `.log`.